# Caching data with Firebase Realtime Database & Flutter - how do I make a query refresh & override the cache?

Tags: flutter, caching, firebase-realtime-database

I'm doing a search query of data in Realtime Database, but it seems to be only returning cached data and not updating when the data in the database changes. I want to do a new query and either clear that bit of the cache or force override.

Comment: If the device doesn't have network connectivity, the result will come from cache.  Are you sure that your test situation is able to do networking properly?

Comment: "Questions seeking debugging help ('**why isn't this code working?**') must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)"

Answer (score 0):

Here's a nice snippet of code if you want to just read data not stored in cache:

```
!snapshot.data.metadata.isFromCache ? Not from cache  : Something else
```

If you don't want to enable caching, set the persistence to false:

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setPersistenceEnabled(false)
```

Comment: Realtime Database doesn't provide any metadata regarding the state of the cache.  You must be thinking of Firestore, which is a completely different database with different APIs.  It is not the topic of this question.

Comment: @DougStevenson you're right. This works for the Cloud Firestore.